# Custom UINavigationBar Shape in iOS 7

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, uinavigationbar

I am new to iOS development. How can I create a `UINavigationBar` like the one below? Which method do I need to override and how could I achieve a shape like that one?

[image: Custom UINavigationBar Shape]

Comment: Why can't you just give it a background image?? Why do you need to override anything? `- (void)setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)backgroundImage forBarMetrics:(UIBarMetrics)barMetrics`

Comment: Because I want to solve this problem programmatically.

Comment: This is solving it programmatically, I have already given the method you need to set. There is no need to override any methods.

Comment: You could subclass UINavigationBar and do some custom drawing in `-drawRect:`.

Comment: @JoeFryer Seems a bit extreme when there is a method there for you to use already.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the shape of the navigation bar. You can however create the illusion of the shape with custom controls and images.

Comment: So the only way to achieve the above shape is to use an image?

Comment: A single or a combination of images, depending on what look do you exactly want to achieve. It should also be the safest and most stable way of doing it.